# Make auto-keyed animation smoother

Tags: animation, keyframes

Autokeying makes the animation look very janky and rough, how can I make it more smooth?

Comment: in the Prefrences > Animation > F Curves, is Default Inteprolation set to Bezier?

Comment: @moonboots yeah

Comment: I think this'll help.
https://youtu.be/r9i6g-pToVM?si=HcVC8NWdIgDuoOA7&t=400
----____---